# I want to write a post on the wall of the Facebook group but it does not support the work of the robot

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with Facebook using the Selenium Python library .... I wrote Script in order to enter the private Facebook group and publish there is no response as an error message arrives that the browser does not support robotic actions Is there a solution to this problem Is eating from the browser or from Facebook  please answer

Comment: Welcome to SO. It looks like you can attach enough reproducible code to your question. Follow SO's guide and attach a minimal reproducible code. Also, please specify which error message was received. Questions should give more clear information to community members. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Only way Facebook allows you to interact with them is their API.

Answer (score 0):

Automating FB, Gmail etc through Selenium is not recommended.

Please see the documentation on [Selenium Worst Practices](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/gmail_email_and_facebook_logins/)

Based on the documentation:

> The ideal practice is to use the  developer tools service which
> exposes an API for creating test accounts, friends and so forth.
> Although using an API might seem like a bit of extra hard work, you
> will be paid back in speed, reliability, and stability. The API is
> also unlikely to change, whereas webpages and HTML locators change
> often and require you to update your test framework.